# if else with an optional value

Tags: php

I can't figure this out. I need to do and if else.

If A is not empty then it must equal B & C must = D & E must = F

It is the A & B part I think that has me messed up. I cant get it to work only if A is not empty

```
 if( ( !empty($data[0]) && trim($data[0]) == $_POST['firstname'] ) || trim($data[1]) == $_POST['lastname'] && $_POST['password'] == $password)
```

It is that A is optional that gets me.

Comment: you wrote || between B & C instead &&

Comment: for security, one should avoid working with actual passwords. They should be hashed. ie don't say `if($_POST['password']==$password)`; rather say `if(hash($_POST['password'])==$hashed_password)'. Oh, and never store an unencrypted password in your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do it all in one go?

```
If (A is not empty) then 
    if A == B && C == D && E == F then
```

Which I think comes out as:

```
if ( !empty($data[0]) {
   if ((trim($data[0]) == $_POST['firstname'] ) && trim($data[1]) == $_POST['lastname'] && $_POST['password'] == $password) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
if( !empty($a) && ($a==$b && $c == $d && e == $f)) {
 // Carry On
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to nest your conditionals.....

The following should work (provided you really mean what you question says):

```
if( ( empty(data[0]) || (!empty($data[0]) && trim($data[0]) == $_POST['firstname'] )) && trim($data[1]) == $_POST['lastname'] && $_POST['password'] == $password )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(
    (!empty($data[0]) && 
        (trim($data[0]) == $_POST['firstname']) &&
         trim($data[1]) == $_POST['lastname'] &&
         $_POST['password'] == $password)
    )
)
```